# Grey background if link is activated on Ipad/Iphone

Tags: ios, hyperlink, webview

If a link in a webview on an ios device is touched it gets a grey background. is there any possibility to prevent this?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent it? That's how the user knows they touched in the right place.

Comment: I am using a different indicator that the user has touched the link. It's like an dropdown menue and the short appearence of the grey background is irratating.

Answer (score 4):

Use the -webkit-tap-highlight-color CSS property:

```
<div style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(200,0,0,0.0)">No tap highlighting!</div>
```